# Reading in a stata .dta file as a python pandas data frame using pd.read_stata()

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, stata

I want to read in an `.dta` file as a pandas data frame.

I've tried using code from https://www.fragilefamilieschallenge.org/using-dta-files-in-python/ but it gives me an error.

Thanks for any help!

```
import pandas as pd
df_path = "https://zenodo.org/record/3635384/files/B-PROACT1V%20Year%204%20%26%206%20child%20BP%2C%20BMI%20and%20PA%20dataset.dta?download=1"
df = None
with open(df_path, "r") as f:
    df = pd.read_stata(f)
    print df.head()
```

Comment: What error?????

Comment: `open` is only for local files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open` can be used when you have a file saved locally on your machine. With `pd.read_stata` this is not necessary however, as you can specify the file path directly as a parameter.

In this case you want to read in a .dta file from a url so this does not apply. The solution is simple though, as `pd.read_stata` can read in files from urls directly.

```py
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://zenodo.org/record/3635384/files/B-PROACT1V%20Year%204%20%26%206%20child%20BP%2C%20BMI%20and%20PA%20dataset.dta?download=1'
df = pd.read_stata(url)
```